# Host WCF service without config file

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I want to host a WCF service but I don't want to use `app.config` file but something similar to this:

```
// 2nd Procedure:
// Use the binding in a service
// Create the Type instances for later use and the URI for 
// the base address.
Type contractType = typeof(ICalculator);
Type serviceType = typeof(Calculator);
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8036/SecuritySamples/");

// Create the ServiceHost and add an endpoint, then start
// the service.
ServiceHost myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddress);
myServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(contractType, myBinding, "secureCalculator");

//enable metadata
ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
myServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

myServiceHost.Open();
```

After that I want to add a Windows service project and host my service.

What project should I use? I don't want console or winforms, I only want Windows service

I checked `Windows Service project` and i have this main:

```
static void Main()
{
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
    { 
        new Service1() 
    };
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

Where should i put the service code ?

Comment: I'd have to check, but I'm pretty sure there's a Windows Service project template in Visual Studio.  Use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would put the code from your first code block in the `OnStart` function of `Service1`.

```
private _myServiceHost;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    if(_myServiceHost != null)
    {
        //Close the connection if the service was already opened.
        _myServiceHost.Close();
    }

    // 2nd Procedure:
    // Use the binding in a service
    // Create the Type instances for later use and the URI for 
    // the base address.
    Type contractType = typeof(ICalculator);
    Type serviceType = typeof(Calculator);
    Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8036/SecuritySamples/");

    // Create the ServiceHost and add an endpoint, then start
    // the service.
    _myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddress);
    _myServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(contractType, myBinding, "secureCalculator");

    //enable metadata
    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    _myServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

    _myServiceHost.Open();
}

//Adding a close on OnStop gives you a more graceful shutdown of your service, letting clients finish the work they are currently on
protected override void OnStop()
{
    if(_myServiceHost != null)
    {
        _myServiceHost.Close();
        _myServiceHost = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

below you can find a working example:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    public class SMTX_Service : ISMTX_Service
    {
    }
 private void StartService(Uri baseUri, string EndPointName, bool EnableServiceDiscovery)
        {
                var serviceUri = new Uri(baseUri, EndPointName);
                Host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCF_TEST.SMTX_Service), baseUri);
                Host.Faulted += h_ServiceFaulted;
                Host.Opened += h_ServiceOpened;
                Host.Closed += h_ServiceClosed;
                WSHttpBinding wsHttpBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
                wsHttpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
                wsHttpBinding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite.TripleDesSha256Rsa15;
                wsHttpBinding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = true;
                wsHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
                wsHttpBinding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = true;
                wsHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
                wsHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
                wsHttpBinding.Security.Transport.Realm = "";
                wsHttpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288;
                wsHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 4194304;
                ServiceEndpoint SEP = Host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(WCF_TEST.ISMTX_Service), wsHttpBinding, EndPointName);
                SEP.Name = EndPointName;
                SEP.Address = new EndpointAddress(serviceUri);
                SEP.Binding = wsHttpBinding;
                ServiceMetadataBehavior SMB = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                SMB.HttpGetEnabled = EnableServiceDiscovery;
                Host.Description.Behaviors.Add(SMB);
                ServiceCredentials SC = new ServiceCredentials();
                SC.ServiceCertificate.Certificate = GetCertificate();
                SC.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
                SC.UseIdentityConfiguration = false;
                SC.ClientCertificate.Certificate = GetCertificate();
                SC.WindowsAuthentication.AllowAnonymousLogons = false;
                SC.WindowsAuthentication.IncludeWindowsGroups = true;
                SC.Peer.PeerAuthentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
                Host.Description.Behaviors.Add(SC);
                Host.Open();
        }
```

the above example uses certificates from certificates' store for authentication. the function GetCertificate is not included. change the message algorithm and negotiation as needed.
you can start the service as follow :

```
StartService(new Uri("..."), "WCF_NAME", true);
```

Comment: I think is question more is he does not know where to put the `StartService(...` call, not what to put in that call.

Comment: yes you are right @ScottChamberlain i didn't pay attention. but the full code might be useful for someone :)

Comment: Where i need to put it and this is with security ? (i prefer without)